# Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/auth/registerMe Gateway Timeout

Tags: node.js, angularjs, docker, express

I have a MEAN App running inside ubuntu virtual machine in my windows Computer.I run this using docker-compose up.Now the containers are running but when I tried to register the form it shows error
"Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/auth/registerMe"

Gateway timeout

My proxy.config.json

```
{
"/auth/*": {
"target": "http://localhost:8080",
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug",
"changeOrigin": true
}
}
```

My nginx.conf file

```
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
upstream client{
server client:4200;
}
upstream server{
server server:8080;
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name *.*;
location / {

proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
}
location /api {
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
proxy_pass http://server;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}
}
```

Any Help Appreciated